# vlc SAP discovery using browser plugin

Tags: google-chrome, stream, udp, vlc

I have the vlc plugin installed for chrome browser. I am receiving SAP broadcasts, which I can normally use and play  using the standalone vlc application. I want to know if the same is possible using the vlc plugin. If not,  can I just play the UDP streams using the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SAP discovery available in VLC's NPAPI plugins. However, you can indeed receive UDP streams just fine.